# In atom editor using hydrogen for jupyter/python, how to extract/save an image?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor, hydrogen

Is there a straightforward way (one line code or even context menu) to save an image that is shown in a return bubble from the Hydrogen package in the Atom.io editor?

I actually managed to extract the base64 code for the png from the developer-pane inspecting the bubble, and this can be used to generate the image. However, that is very cumbersome and it's easier to use pyhton to save the image (see below).

Remark: 
Of course, since python is used to generate the image, it is in principle possible to save the image by injecting python code, however, sometime I just want to save the picture generated without going back to the file that contains the code that generates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible due to an Atom limitation. See: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/245